# Проблема с размещением сокета PostgreSQL в Unix

Tags: сокет, postgresql

По умолчанию в Ubuntu сокет бд-сервера, очевидно, должен хранится в папке /var/run/postgresql, однако при каждой установке он у меня оказывается в /tmp. Поэтому при обращения большинства приложений (например Rails) к серверу появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

как мне переместить сокет в нужную папку, или переназначить системные переменные чтобы искали его в другой папке?

Comment: Что значит "инициализировать строку"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена: в файле `$PGDATA/postgresql.conf` раскоментировать и инициализировать строку `unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/'` + перезапуск сервера.

Comment: а где находиться файл $PGDATA/postgresql.conf ?

Answer (score 3):

`postgresql.conf` находится в директории `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main`

9.5 - версия БД, у Вас может отличаться.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu 18.04 Мне помогло копирование файлов из `/etc/postgresql/10/main` в `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main` сделать это можно только дав права на запись типа `chmod 777 main` с последующим возвратом к `chmod 700`, либо же под пользователем postgres. Обязательно посмотрите лог файл который в моем случае лежит в `/var/lib/postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

Для исходного кода PostgreSQL по-умолчанию [используется именно `/tmp`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/include/pg_config_manual.h#L182).

Однако этот путь не прибит гвоздями, это константа в коде `DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR` и некоторые сопровождающие пакетов предпочитают изменять путь на предпочтительный для дистрибьютива. В частности, пакеты для `Ubuntu` и `Debian` обычно собираются с изменением этого пути на `/var/run/postgresql/`.

И это изменение не представляет каких-то проблем, но только пока ваши приложения использующую базу собраны с тем же самым `DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR`. Если используемая в системе библиотека `libpq` была собрана с одним `DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR`, а СУБД с другим - то вы будете получать такие ошибки. Поэтому лучше всего проверить, какие именно вы используете пакеты самой СУБД, а какие приложениями и `libpq`. Очевидно они собраны с разными настройками, возможно получены из разных репозиториев. Я как postgresql DBA рекомендую использовать штатные репозитории [PostgreSQL Global Development Group](https://www.postgresql.org/download/)

---

Другая возможность, как уже верно отмечено, это сконфигурировать СУБД слушать сокет не по адресу с которым та была скомпилирована, а с указанным вручную. За это отвечает конфигурационная опция `unix_socket_directories` (вот [тут можно заметить](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/utils/misc/guc.c#L3644), что дефолтное значение и есть константа `DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR`)

Где находится сам конфигурационный файл `postgresql.conf` - вопрос отдельный и специфичен опять же для предпочтений того человека, кто собирал СУБД. Хоть это и не опции сборки (имя `postgresql.conf` захардкожено в путях), но размещается он в каталоге образно названным `$PGDATA`. То есть где угодно, лишь бы этот каталог был указан при инициализации и затем при каждом старте СУБД. А так же файл конфигурации может лежать где угодно если опцией запуска config_file указать путь к нему при запуске СУБД.

В `ubuntu` и `debian` **обычно** раскладывают таким образом:
 - файлы конфигурации в `/etc/postgresql/(номер major версии postgresql)/main`
 - `$PGDATA` размещается по пути `/var/lib/postgresql/(номер major версии postgresql)/main`

В CentOS же например `$PGDATA` размещается в `/var/lib/pgsql/(номер major версии postgresql)/data`, там же файл конфигурации.

А вот если, как в вашем случае, имеет место несогласованное состояние установленных пакетов - то могут быть сюрпризы. Гарантированно узнать с какого конфигурационного файла PostgreSQL начал работу можно запросом

```
show config_file;
```

В ответ будет путь до файла конфигурации. Останется только привести опцию `unix_socket_directories` к виду `unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql/'` и перезапустить СУБД: `unix_socket_directories` может изменяться только при рестарте всей СУБД.

PS: стоит ещё прокомментировать, что до выпуска 9.3 опция называлась `unix_socket_directory`. Современная `unix_socket_directories` допускает перечисление сразу нескольких директорий через запятую.

Answer (score 0):

найти файл сокета s.PGSQL.5432

```
find / -name s.PGSQL.5432
```

указать найденный каталог при подключении после ключа -h
например:

```
psql -h /var/lib/postgresql/13
```