# Установка PostgreSQL. Как настроить pg_hba.conf и postgresql.conf?

Tags: linux, база-данных, postgresql, linux-mint

При вводе команды `psql -U postgres`

на выводе получаю следующее

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Нагуглил что проблема в конфигах postgresql и pg_hba. В первом все по дефолту, слушает локалхост, 32 порт. А вот со вторым проблемы, пытался по разному, но не выходит. В итоге откатил его до дефолтного состояния.

```
local   all             postgres                                all

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Жду советов мудрых.

Comment: Прослушай [этот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_GdEaF1Ymc&list=PLaFqU3KCWw6KzGwUubZm-9-vKsi6vh5qC) замечательный курс и все поймешь.

Comment: Начинал смотреть, но дропнул. Ибо когда теория началась, на втором видосе вроде, понял что нет даже зачаточных данных по БД. Скачал пакет, думал будет **ВСЕИЗКАРБОКИ**

Comment: Лично я не видел лучшего курса по администрации PostgreSQL. Все, что ты написал, рассказывается в курсе.

Comment: Убедил, пойду наверну. Плюс в первом же курсе по основам SQL, неправильный синтаксис для постргеса дают.

Comment: psql -h localhost -U postgres. Или так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23878/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-postgresql-%D0%B2-unix

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/auth-pg-hba-conf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема решилась заменой метода `all` на `trust` в первой строке.

Answer (score -1):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой, но изменения в pg_hba не помогали.
Иногда пропадает ссылка на сокет файл.
Попробуйте пересоздать:

ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]